# Problems adding to two dimensional list in java

Tags: java, arrays, list, multidimensional-array

I don't understand why this cannot work, if anyone could help that would be great;

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10 ; i++){
    lines = fileL[i];
    for(int j = 0; j < lines.length(); j++){
        enemySpawningL[i][j] = fileL[i].substring(j*2, 1);
    }
}
```

where enemySpawning[][] has been set as a string and fileL is set as this;

```
private String[] fileL = {
    "1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1",
    "1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 2 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 2 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1",
    "1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1",
    "1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1",
    "1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 2 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 2 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 2 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 2 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 2",
    "1 0 0 0 1 0 2 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 2 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 2 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 2 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 2 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 2 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 2 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 2 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 2 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 2 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 2 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 2 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 2 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 2 0 1 0 0 0 1",
    "1 0 3 0 1 0 2 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 2 0 1 0 3 0 1 0 2 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 2 0 1 0 3 0 1 0 2 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 2 0 1 0 3 0 1 0 2 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 2 0 1 0 3 0 1 0 2 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 2 0 1 0 3 0 1 0 2 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 2 0 1 0 3 0 1 0 2 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 2 0 1 0 3 0 1",
    "1 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 3 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 3 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 3 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 1",
    "2 0 0 3 0 2 0 0 3 0 2 0 0 3 0 2 0 0 3 0 2 0 0 3 0 2 0 0 3 0 2 0 0 3 0 2 0 0 3 0 2 0 0 3 0 2 0 0 3 0 2 0 0 3 0 2 0 0 3 0 2 0 0 3 0 2 0 0 3 0 2 0 0 3 0 2 0 0 3 0 2 0 0 3 0 2 0 0 3 0 2 0 0 3 0 2 0 0 3",
    "2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2",
};
```

(I tried using a textfile for it, but I didn't think there was a point cause it's not too important)

EDIT: I'm just trying to make the enemySpawning list be [line number][number in line]

EDIT2: Also the error I'm getting is java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: What are you trying to do? what is the expected output?

Comment: @guy I changed my post so you can see

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is probably because you didn't initialize `enemySpawningL`.

```
String[][] enemySpawningL = new String[rowsNum][columnsNum];
```

And if I understand correctly what you are trying to do change your code to

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; ++i) {
    String[] digits = fileL[i].split(" ");
    for(int j = 0 ; j < digits.length ; ++j) {
        enemySpawningL[i][j] = digits[j];
    }
}
```

That will give you one digit in every cell. Currently your substring() is wrong as the start point is bigger than the end point for j > 0 and if you change the order you insert string with several digits every time.

```
"1"
"1 0"
"1 0 0"
....
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, as @guy mentioned, not initializing the array, but there is also another error in here:

```
enemySpawningL[i][j] = fileL[i].substring(j*2, 1);
```

Because 'j' can have maximal value of `fileL[i]` length, if you request index `j`*2, in half of the loop it will be out of bound. You are also using the `substring` method in incorrect way. How you want you loop to look like is:

```
for(int j = 0; j < lines.length(); j += 2){
    enemySpawningL[i][j] = fileL[i].substring(j, j+1);
}
```

The `j` variable is now incremented by two every iteration (to skip spaces) and `substring` will return one character from position `j` of the string `file[L]`. Which is what you wanted.